# Why won't my AJAX work with Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a page that is basically a storefront with items for sale. I have some filters in the nav bar to filter product. When I click a filter, I am trying to get the products related to that filter to load (without refreshing the page) via AJAX.  Currently when I click a filter, the store items disappear but do not repopulate with relevant items. I am getting the following error in chrome dev console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined   jquery.2.1.1.min.css
```

I'm not sure what's going on, I have been following this tutorial http://westiseast.co.uk/blog/django-ajax-update-queryset-introduction/, which is really outdated so I don't know if my problem may be related to using a tutorial that relies on deprecated libraries or practices (I'm using Django 1.6).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

VIEWS.PY

```
def storefront(request):
    latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
    context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}

if request.is_ajax():
    if request.GET.get('filter') == 'recent':
        new_list = []
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
        new_list.append(render_to_string('storefrontload.html', {'latest_entries': latest_entries}))
        json =  simplejson.dumps(new_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", home),
    url(r"^storefront/", storefront))
```

STOREFRONT.HTML

```
<a href="" id=most_recent>Show Recent</a>

{% include "storefrontload.html" %}

<script>
function filter(type) {
$.getJSON("/storefront/", {xhr: "true", filter: type},
  function(data) {
    $('.container').children().remove();
    $(data).appendTo('.container');
  });
}

$("#most_recent").click(function () { 
  filter("recent");
  $('#most_recent').attr('style', 'font-weight: bold').css('color', '#000'); 
});
return false;
</script>
```

STOREFRONTLOAD.HTML

```
<div class="bodydiv">
    <div class="container">
    {% for i in latest_entries %}
      <div class="grid_4">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="{{ i.item_picture.url }}" alt="" />
          <div class="overlayname">{{ i.headline }}</div>
          <div class="overlayprice">{{ i.price1 }}</div>
          </div>
        <div class="textcontainer">
        <p>{{ i.body_text }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sellerdiv">
        <div class="sellerpic"><a href="/accounts/{{ i.author }}"><img src="{{ i.author.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}"></a></div> 
        <div class="sellerinfo">Sold by <b>{{ i.author }}</b></div>
        <div class="hearts"><img src="/static/img/stars.png"></div>
        <div class="reviewnum"></div>
        <div class="posteddate">Posted {{ i.pub_date|timesince|upto:',' }} ago</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML/JSON that is returned when filter is invoked? Also, and just as a note, I wouldn't bother converting the HTML into JSON as your code is looking to be solely working with HTML, which may explain the Dev console error you're seeing

Comment: `$("#most_recent").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: also for serialization using `simplejson.dumps` use `latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3).values('some_field1', 'some_field2', 'etc',)` `my_json = mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(list(latest_entries), ensure_ascii=False))`

Comment: and replace `simplejson` with `json`, you can import it this way `import json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need json actually, just return the partial html

```
if request.is_ajax():
   if request.GET.get('filter') == 'recent':
       latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
       context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
       return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

and  in html:

```
function filter(type) {
  $.get("/storefront/?filter="+type, function(data) {
     $('.container').children().remove();
     $(data).appendTo('.container');
  });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Is there any advantage of using Ajax to achieve this type of functionality?  I didn't know I could call a new query without refreshing the page (without using ajax).

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia yep ajax is very nice thing: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583223/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-making-ajax-calls-using-jquery