# Why is Sending Data with JQuery Necessary?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What are the advantages of using jQuery Ajax to POST data to the backend?

Is it necessary to use jQuery Ajax to POST if your html and php are on the same page? (meaning it only reloads, not redirect, after being submitted traditionally).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583223/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-making-ajax-calls-using-jquery

Comment: read this also:http://www.jscripters.com/ajax-disadvantages-and-advantages/

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use jQuery or vanilla JavaScript is your choice.  Ajax is useful if you just want to send a small size of data to the server without downloading the entire page from the server.

Suppose you have a page with 1000s of lines of HTML and you need to submit a simple yes or no response to a question to the server.  Now, if you just redirect to the same page, it will still download most of the HTML page again.  Ajax will just send that bit of data you want to send to the server and get a response which you can use within the client side to make changes to the page.